# Nombre de los adjetivos que significan "relacionado a" (bélico, académico, etc.)

Tags: vocabulario, adjetivos, lingüística, categorías-gramaticales

En español hay una serie de palabras que significan "relacionado a (algo)"
Por ejemplo:

- Bélico: Relacionado a la guerra
- Académico: Relacionado a la educacion
- Eclesiástico: Relativo a la iglesia

etc.

¿Hay algun nombre para este tipo de palabras?

Comment: No son sustantivos sinó adjetivos.

Comment: Muchas gracias rodrigo. Cambie tanto el titulo como las tags para evitar confusion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se trata de **adjetivos relacionales** o **adjetivos de relación**:

> 1. m. Gram. adjetivo que especifica el ámbito o el dominio que corresponde al sustantivo al que modifica y que suele caracterizarse con la fórmula «perteneciente o relativo a»; p. ej., literario en Crítica literaria.